# 敬語 with and without ～になる

Tags: word-choice, words, keigo

When asking someone politely to, for example, look at something, you can say both ご覧になっていただけますか following the standard 敬語, but you can also say ご覧いただけますか. Is there any particular difference between the two, such as that one may be politer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You guessed it.** The former, ご覧になっていただけますか <strike>contains multiple 敬語</strike> (*edit!* has no omission), so it's a little bit politer than the latter.

EDIT: Sorry, scratch this:
<strike>Some say that such form is 二重{にじゅう}敬語 (using 2 or more 敬語 in the same unit of sentence) and wrong to use, but it is widespread in Japan already (so it's not *too* wrong) - also, 二重敬語 can be found everywhere in old Japanese. 二重敬語 in old Japanese has been used against the emperor, his relative, etc., who were in very high rank. So it can be said that ご覧になっていただけますか is politer than ご覧いただけますか.</strike>

---

EDIT: **I'M SORRY, I WAS WRONG!** Actually ご覧になっていただけますか has no 二重敬語 in it!
The original form of ご覧になっていただく is **見て/もらう**.

- 見る in 尊敬語 form is ご覧になる.
- もらう in 謙譲語 form is いただく.

Together, they make ご覧になっていただく. 二重敬語 refers to using 敬語 against the same verb like ご覧になられる (confusing なる in ご覧になる as a word.)
Nevertheless, I was feeling something was wrong - and it is the fact that this sentence has 2 verbs (見る and もらう) that made me feel some oddity.
So the proper explanation will be that, both of them are A-OK, and **ご覧いただけますか is just a short form of ご覧になっていただけますか**. I think the level of politeness of ご覧になっていただけますか is a little bit, *just a little bit* higher because it's the *full* form.

Comment: I personally don't feel either are more polite.

Comment: 似た形で「おいでになっていただけますか」「お越しになっていただけますか」は変な気がしますね～不思議～

Comment: じつは間違ってないようなんですよね、、、

Answer (score 0):

見てもらえますか is divided into these words.

> 見る　…ご覧になる(honorific language)
>   　もらう…いただく(honorific language)

Therefore, the sentence as follows is made from them.

> ご覧になっていただけますか

For example, in the case of 見てください, it is as follows.

> 見てください
>   　　↓
>   　ご覧になってください(honorific language)

Though, that is often shorted like this.

> ご覧ください(honorific language)

I think there is almost no difference in those meanings.
Furthermore, as in the case of お支払いになってください→お支払いください, there are cases where an abbreviated style is more natural.